# CMD Choice high-range characters

Tags: command-line, ascii

As a test, I tried this:

> C:\Users\Kolink>choice /C `
>   ERROR: Invalid choice. The valid choice characters are: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and ASCII values of 128 to 254.

How exactly would I add ASCII values in the range 128-254 to my list of choices, and how would they be chosen by the user?

Answer (score 1):

An example would be Ç:

```
choice /c YÇ
[Y,Ç]
```

This can be generated by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing <kbd>128</kbd> on the numeric keypad.  However, some keyboards may have this more accessible, particularly where the character is used in their language.